# Picking which data to view in group by

Tags: php, sql

So yesterday, I am trying to sort data in groups made by *Group by*
I must select which data I want to show in those group
There is list of debts and each person may be in debt in the past but never have more than 1 unpaid debt
I need to know how many times how many times each user have been in debt before this last debt.


This is the column in the data base

> Table "Users" 
>   uid | name | date_of_birth
>   
>   Table "Debt"
>   uid | debt_duration | paid_count | created_date

I end up with a hack like this in php

```
$res = mysql_query( "
       SELECT * FROM Debt 
       JOIN Users
       WHERE Users.uid = Debt.uid 
       ORDER BY created_date 
       GROUP BY Debt.uid");

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $res ) ){
     $uid = $row['uid'];
     $r = mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Debt WHERE uid = $uid") );
     $previous_debts_count = $r[0];

}
```

This script is quite heavy but fortunately my client doesn't complain. 
The script run at around 3 seconds top

But I need to know better ways to do this

sorry for the strange formatting, I am new here ...

Comment: On which columns do you have indexes? And how many rows are we talking about?

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct.  Can you describe what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the query you want is this:

```
SELECT Users.uid, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM Debt JOIN 
     Users 
     ON Users.uid = Debt.uid 
GROUP BY Debt.uid
ORDER BY created_date ;
```

Just loop through the results and don't use multiple queries for this.  Check that `Users.uid` is the primary key on the users table.  And add an index on `debt(uid)` to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should **never** use * in an SQL statement.
It makes the query highly vulnerable to SQL injection.

And I recommend you to use a PDO or a PHP framework.

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Debt.uid) AS users
FROM Debt
LEFT JOIN Users
ON Users.uid = Debt.uid
GROUP BY Debt.uid
```

Comment: I didn't use * but to keep things brief and there is more column than that. Anyway,  What I am concern about is it keep show the debt that has already been paid I want to show the debt that haven't been paid. Sorry for my late edit

Comment: I'd think about using a "payed" flag. If the flag is TRUE then the debt is already payed so you could insert a "WHERE payed = 0" section into the query.

Comment: Doing that will counting the previous debt wrong, there will only one data where payed = 0 for each person..